# Plot da Curva CL50 no R utilizando ggplot2 com estimativas obtidas no stan

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, regressão

Estou tentando fazer o seguinte gráfico abaixo no ggplot2.
Veja que estou ajustando um modelo de regressão logística sob a abordagem bayesiana utilizando o pacote stan.

```
library(dplyr)
library(rstanarm)
library(ggplot2)
dados<- read.table("dados.csv", header = T, sep=";", dec = ",")
dados$periodo <-  as.factor(dados$periodo)
dados <- dados %>% mutate(proporcao =  (dados$resposta)/60)
dados <- dados %>% mutate(logdose = log(dados$concentracao))
dados<- mutate(dados, 
               C_resposta=60-resposta)
fitstanglm24 <- stan_glm(cbind(resposta, C_resposta)~ logdose, 
                         family = binomial(link = "logit"), 
                         data = dados,
                         subset=periodo=="24h")
summary(fitstanglm24)
plot(dados$proporcao[dados$periodo=="24h"]~dados$logdose[dados$periodo=="24h"], 
     pch=16, main="Experiment Duration: 24h", col="black", lwd=3, xlim=c(-8,-1),
     ylim=c(0,1),xlab="log(Concentrations g.a.i/L)",
     ylab="Proportion of bees killed")
lines(c(-3.53,-3.53),c(0,0.50),lty=3)
lines(c(-3.53,-8),c(0.50,0.50),lty=3)
legend(-7.8,0.52,c(expression(paste(LC[50], "= -3.53"))),bty="n",cex=1.1)
points(fitstanglm24$fitted.values~dados$logdose[dados$periodo=="24h"], 
       pch=16, col="red", lwd=3)
curve(plogis(coef(fitstanglm48)[1] + coef(fitstanglm48)[2]*x),-10,-1,
      add=TRUE, col="black",lty=2)
legend("topleft",c("Real Values","Adjusted Values"), 
       col=c("black","red"),pch=16)
```

[image]

No entanto, o seguinte erro aparece.

```
ggplot(data = dados, aes(x = dados$logdose[dados$periodo=="24h"], y = (dados$proporcao[dados$periodo=="24h"]))) + 
   geom_point(size = 2, colour = "#FF4D87") +
   labs(title="Experiment Duration: 24h",
        x ="log(Concentrations g.a.i/L)", y = "Proportion of bees killed") +
   theme(
      plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 15),
      plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 12),
      axis.title.x = element_text(size = 13),
      axis.title.y = element_text(size = 13)) +
   geom_smooth(method = "glm", lwd = 1.4, 
               method.args = list(family = binomial(link = "logit")), 
               aes(weight = total), colour = "#FF4D87", se = TRUE, fill = "#FFA2C1")
Erro: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (15): x and y
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Além disso:

```
Warning messages:
1: Use of `dados$logdose` is discouraged. Use `logdose` instead. 
2: Use of `dados$periodo` is discouraged. Use `periodo` instead. 
3: Use of `dados$proporcao` is discouraged. Use `proporcao` instead. 
4: Use of `dados$periodo` is discouraged. Use `periodo` instead.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Os *warnings* dão uma boa dica do que está havendo:

```
Warning messages:
1: Use of `dados$logdose` is discouraged. Use `logdose` instead. 
2: Use of `dados$periodo` is discouraged. Use `periodo` instead. 
3: Use of `dados$proporcao` is discouraged. Use `proporcao` instead. 
4: Use of `dados$periodo` is discouraged. Use `periodo` instead.
```

É recomendado não referenciar as colunas dos conjuntos de dados no esquema `dados$coluna` para fazer um gráfico no `ggplot`. É sempre preferível chamar diretamente os nomes das variáveis. Sendo assim, sugiro fazer a filtragem dos dados para o período de 24 horas antes de fazer o gráfico, da seguinte maneira:

```r
dados %>%
  filter(periodo == "24h") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = logdose, y = proporcao)) + 
  geom_point(size = 2, colour = "#FF4D87") +
  labs(title="Experiment Duration: 24h",
       x ="log(Concentrations g.a.i/L)", y = "Proportion of bees killed") +
  theme(
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 15),
    plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 12),
    axis.title.x = element_text(size = 13),
    axis.title.y = element_text(size = 13)) +
  geom_smooth(method = "glm", lwd = 1.4, 
              method.args = list(family = binomial(link = "logit")), 
              aes(weight = total), colour = "#FF4D87", se = TRUE, fill = "#FFA2C1")
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula 'y ~ x'
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-12-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Só tenha ciência de que a função plotada no gráfico é calculada de maneira frequentista. Dessa forma, seus coeficientes são ligeiramente diferentes daqueles estimados pelo modelo bayesiano (que, na realidade, serão sempre diferentes devido à natureza da estimação dos parâmetros via MCMC).

```r
fitstanglm24$coefficients
#> (Intercept)     logdose 
#>   2.2127430   0.6233138
dados_24 <- filter(dados, periodo == "24h")
glm(proporcao ~ logdose, data = dados_24, family = binomial(link = "logit"))
#> Warning in eval(family$initialize): non-integer #successes in a binomial glm!
#> 
#> Call:  glm(formula = proporcao ~ logdose, family = binomial(link = "logit"), 
#>     data = dados_24)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#> (Intercept)      logdose  
#>       2.184        0.616  
#> 
#> Degrees of Freedom: 4 Total (i.e. Null);  3 Residual
#> Null Deviance:       1.003 
#> Residual Deviance: 0.04174   AIC: 8.217
```

<sup>Created on 2020-12-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>